# Clustering on Highly Connected Networkx Undirected Graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am working on an HR project where I have to take employee skills and relate them in such a way that I can create a skills taxonomy. I chose to create an undirected network graph where any time two skills are taken together in an employee's skill-set, it draws an edge between them and the weight of it is how many times those related skills are taken by employees.

There are about 8000 nodes and millions of connections in that graph. My next task is to cluster that graph in such a way that I can see what skills are similar.

The problem is that all the algorithms (ex: connected subgraph components, clustering etc) provided in NetworkX only work for 2000 nodes. When I try to increase the number of nodes, I don't get clear results.

Is there a way I can cluster on 8000 very connected nodes? Any suggestions? I am working in Python.